# What kind of animation/drawing style is used on K-On! Ura-on?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history, k-on

K-On! Ura-on are bonus episodes from the anime K-On! and they used a different kind of animation or drawing style.

[image]

This is the first time I've ever encountered such style (very different compared to the series, though you can easily tell the resemblance to the original) and was wondering for this style's name, if it have. Also, did other anime used this prior or after K-On! Ura-on was released? And, what is this style's history and background? Or is this just created to be unique or random reasons by the K-On! production?

Comment: Generically speaking, this is an example of "super-deformed" style, albeit a particularly unusual example. I'm guessing the particular details of the way the characters were drawn had as much to do with the preferences of the animators in charge as anything, but I expect somebody can probably come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is actually the [super deformed style.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_deformed) Wikipedia describes it as:

> Super deformed or SD is a specific style of Japanese caricature where
>   characters are drawn in an exaggerated way, typically small and
>   chubby, with stubby limbs and oversized heads, to make them resemble
>   small children. This style forms an integral part of what Japanese and
>   American anime fans refer to as chibi.

Some examples:

[image]